# How to observe a child object using KnockoutJS and mapping plugin?

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, viewmodel

With a JSON like that:

***JSON string***

```
{ 
  "SelectedOption" : {}, 
  "Options" : [ 
    { "ID": 0, "Name": "Zero" },
    { "ID": 1, "Name": "One" }
  ] 
}
```

**The question is:** How can I tell to mapping plugin that the `SelectedOption` property is an **ko.observable**?

***Client Code***

```
var _json = '{
               "SelectedOption" : {},
               "Options" : [   
                 { "ID": 0, "Name": "Zero" },
                 { "ID": 1, "Name": "One" }    
               ]
             }';

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(_json);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I wrote a jsfiddle to show the problem 
http://jsfiddle.net/BvVce/3/

Comment: A working example with a complex object http://jsfiddle.net/BvVce/8/

Comment: Refer to this answer I have answered similar question [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24670804/2764258

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide a custom mapping to indicate to the mapping function how it should do it. I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvVce/4/).

Here's the custom mapping, and the changed call to ko.mapping:

```
var mapping = {
    'SelectedOption': {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.observable(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(_json, mapping);
```

And then, in your HTML, you have to add the "()" characters to `SelectedOption` because it is now an observable, like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: SelectedOption().ID"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks. What about an array of objects with a property like that? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You mean an array of selectable options ? If that's the case, instead of returning a ko.observable you can return a ko.observableArray mapped with ko.utils.arrayMap I guess.

Comment: @Tocco I updated another version of your fiddle with an observable array allowing to select multiple options so you can check out how it can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/BvVce/6/

Comment: no I mean a ko.observableArray containing objects like that: { "ID": 9, "SelectedOption": { "ID": 1, "Name": "One" } } ... I want to observe the "SelectedOption" property of each array object.

Comment: @Tocco well yes you can, it's very similar to what I've done in my updated fiddle.

Comment: @Tocco took me some time, but here: http://jsfiddle.net/BvVce/9/ I could not find a way other than "rebinding" the properly selected option manually... I think you could ask another question with that, I am curious if there is a better way...