# Knockout mapping does represent wished for html

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a problem with knockout mapping. I'm using knockout mapping plugin to represent a form that is serialized in JSON. It was working before using the knockout mapping but I need to use knockout mapping since I want my properties to be observable.

You can see the working html here : http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/wG9SZ

**Here's my not working javascript code:**

```
var formData = 
    {"data": 
        [
            {
            "groupName" : "Properties",
            "content" : 
            [
                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Method",
                    "formType" : "select",
                    "value" : 
                    [
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Unbalanced",
                            "selected" : true
                        },
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Balanced"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Tolerance (% V)",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "value" : 0.01
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Options",
                    "formType" : "radio",
                    "value" : 
                    [ 
                        {
                            "title" : "Flat Start (at Nominal Conditions",
                            "checked" : false
                        } ,
                        {
                            "title" : "Assume Line Transposition",
                            "checked" : true
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Adjust Conductor Resistance at",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "disabled" : true,
                    "value" : 77,
                    "appendLabel" : true,
                    "appendLabelText" : "°F"    
                }
            ]
            },
            {
            "groupName" : "Properties",
            "content" : 
            [
                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Method",
                    "formType" : "select",
                    "value" : 
                    [
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Unbalanced",
                            "selected" : true
                        },
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Balanced"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Tolerance (% V)",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "value" : 0.01
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Options",
                    "formType" : "radio",
                    "value" : 
                    [ 
                        {
                            "title" : "Flat Start (at Nominal Conditions",
                            "checked" : false
                        } ,
                        {
                            "title" : "Assume Line Transposition",
                            "checked" : true
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Adjust Conductor Resistance at",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "disabled" : true,
                    "value" : 77,
                    "appendLabel" : true,
                    "appendLabelText" : "°F"    
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
    };  
ko.mapping.fromJS(formData);
```

Here's the jsfiddle of the same code: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/wG9SZ/3/

*What is the problem between when I use mapping and when I don't use it ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second case you forgot to ApplyBindings.

```
ko.applyBindings(formData);
```

Comment: why are my select items not displaying ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I was looking at your binding to try to see.  It's been a little while since I used Knockout.

Comment: thank you, because it worked previously, that is so strange !

Comment: I was missing : <select data-bind="options: $data.value, optionsText: 'title'"></select>, found by @DaveB

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the case with your scenario, but it's worth a post.

I had issues with the mapping plugin, when I had a more complex viewmodel with nested properties or lists. It turned out that after mapping to an already constructed viewmodel, the sub-objects were no more observables. With this issue, for me this code worked, what I've found somewhere (unfortunately I already really don't know where). I called this function for my viewmodel after mapping to that.

```
function makeAllObservables(observable) {
    // Loop through its children
    for (var child in observable()) {
        // If this child is not an observable and is an object
        if ((!ko.isObservable(observable()[child])) && (typeof observable()[child] === "object")) {
            // Make it an observable
            observable()[child] = ko.observable(observable()[child]);
            // Make all of its children observables
            makeAllObservables(observable()[child]);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage (when updating the model from server response, the first line should not be there):

```
var model = ko.observable({});
ko.mapping.fromJS(myJSObject, {}, model);
makeAllObservables(model);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

I ment mapping to an already constructed viewmodel for example, when you want to update your viewmodel with new JSON data from server. In that case I lost nested bindings without the code above.

UPDATE: I've found the source where I borrowed the technique from, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555115/knockout-js-make-every-nested-object-an-observable). Note that I slightly modified that code in that post, because somehow that was not working for me.

Comment: How do you call it exactly. I mean, what is your observable ? What would it be in my case, ko.mapping.fromJS(formData)?

Comment: why do you have that portion of the line: , $('#myform').get(0));

Comment: @CoachNono, because in my case I had more than one forms, and I want to apply this binding only for a specific one. The .get(0) will return the first matched FORM from the jQuery result.

Comment: when I'm doing that, I don't see my forms... http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/wG9SZ/5/

Comment: Yes, because you don't have a form with id "myform". I think you should not use that second parameter. It's only required when you want to apply the bindings inside a specific HTML element. Sorry for confusing, I've removed that from my post.

Comment: I deleted it but still they don't show ... thanks for your help by the way

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected another mistake of mine, I left a "self." qualifier inside the function at the recursive call. I copied it from my original code, that's why I missed it.

Comment: Your code works, however, it is not showing the select items... http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/wG9SZ/15/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32107/discussion-between-zoltan-tamasi-and-coachnono)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the mapped viewmodel to the view:

`ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(formData));`

and since everything is now an observable the logic in the view needs to be changed to use the method syntax:

`<!-- ko if: $data.formType() === "select" -->`

To get the options to display, you need to tell knockout what the property name is on the object:

`<select data-bind="options: $data.value, optionsText: 'title'"></select>`

Comment: thank you, however, I don't see the items in my select after trying that

Comment: When I use your code, my JSON does not get updated, but when using the first person's answer, it does. your <select... helped sort out another problem though ! thank you