# Knockout.js problems viewing objects within objects

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on a prototype questionnaire system. To ask customers questions on the telephone.

Using HTML, JS, KO (and Dynamic CRM as a datasource).

*Note that I'm new to KO as this is day 2! - I am impressed, thought it seems to have an EVE-Online learning curve!*

The questions are stored in Dynamics CRM and retrieved with OData call (returning JSON).

Some questions have child questions, so I de-normalise the original normalised OData result and setup the hierarchy in a new JSON object. Debugging over this object shows its all represented as expected. Tree like.

The problem I have is, I get an when i try to use the view to a certain depth. 
**"Error: Unable to get property 'Value' of undefined or null reference"**

I looked at this article *[Knockout.js Make every nested object an Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555115/knockout-js-make-every-nested-object-an-observable)*, which seemed to be related to my problem, but retro fitting that solution into my code didnt work for me, i may have misunderstood my problem!

My view shows the first level of questions correctly, but the child questions only work up to a point. So when i try and databind this **data-bind="value: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_answertype.Value** i get the null reference error shown above.

However, if I data bind this **data-bind="value: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_answertype** i see "[Object object]" in the view. This to me suggests that it should be able to get the int value of adr_answertype!

The top level adr_answertype.Value bindings work fine, it just seems to be an issue as I get deeper into the object.

**Here is My ViewModel & Model;**

*Note that the Next Questions are meant to be (and are in the JSON) actually Nested questions within the question, which as you can imagine could go arbitrarily deep*

```
function QuestionAnswersVM() {
   var self = this;

   var questionDataRaw = RetrieveQuestionSet("15AF22A6-3E58-E411-B2A6-00155DFD8300", odataPath);

   var questionDataOrganised = OrganiseQuestionHierarchy(questionDataRaw);

   self.questions = ko.mapping.fromJS(questionDataOrganised, mapping);
};

var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        return new Question(options.data);
    }
};

function Question(data) {
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

   // Answers
   this.DateTime = ko.observable(data.DateTime);
   this.FreeText = ko.observable(data.FreeText)
   this.YesNo = ko.observable(data.Yes);

   // Next questions - trying to create nested question here
   this.adr_nextquestionyesid = ko.observable(new Question(data.adr_nextquestionyesid));
}
```

**Here is my View (with unrelated stuff removed);**

*particularly note the databindings within QuesionBoxIndent div which present the problem*

```
<section data-bind="foreach: questions">
<div class="questionBox">
    <span class="questionTitle"><span data-bind="text: adr_name"></span></span>
    <div class="questionBody">
        <label data-bind="text: adr_questionbody" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: adr_answertype().Value == 1">
        <input data-bind="checked: YesNo" type="radio" value="true" />Yes
        <input data-bind="checked: YesNo" type="radio" value="false" />No
        <label class="mandatory" data-bind="visible: $data.adr_mandatory()"><b>*</b></label>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: adr_answertype().Value == 2">
        <input data-bind="value: FreeText" type="text" name="fname" />
        <label class="mandatory" data-bind="visible: $data.adr_mandatory()"><b>*</b></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="questionBoxIndent" data-bind="visible: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_name != null">
    <span class="questionTitle"><span data-bind="text: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_name"></span></span>
    <div class="questionBody">
        <label data-bind="text: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_questionbody" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input data-bind="value: adr_nextquestionyesid().FreeText" type="text" name="fname" />
        <input data-bind="value: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_answertype" type="text" name="fname" />
        <input data-bind="value: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_answertype.Value" type="text" name="fname" />
        <label class="mandatory" data-bind="visible: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_mandatory"><b>*</b></label>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

*Edit: Having spent another day on it, i thought i had cracked it using the suggestion of Sergiu, to use the mapping plugin. I got that to map eventually, but seemingly it doesnt expose the depth which i thought it would. Basically, when trying to access the value on the adr_answertype of the nested question, i get the same **"Error: Unable to get property 'Value' of undefined or null reference"**. I tried all sorts of variations of view syntax to get access to the Value. Even though its definitely there when looking at the original mapped object with a debugger. Maybe I should look to build the model completely manually, that will be a separate stream of research, my reading only shows me how to declare the top level model!*

Many thanks in advance all!

Peace

Comment: Why are you sometimes using `adr_answertype().Value` and other times `adr_answertype.Value`? You do know how an observable works, right?

Comment: The last block of input controls just had various syntax to see if I had something wrong. My knowledge of knockout is patchy as its only day 2, having ran though a number of tutorials and such.

The last div (the one without a databind) would be akin to the ones in the first QuestionBox where they would be databound with data-bind="visible: adr_nextquestionyesid().adr_answertype.Value == 1 for example

Comment: You access an observable's value like this: `someObservable()`. Next you have a `Value` property. If that's not an observable (you don't seem to be accessing it's value by calling the observable (`Value()`) then how is knockout supposed to know it changed? Looks to me you need some sort of _deep observables_ OR manually map that data structure to an observable one.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, the deep observables was where my research was leading. Hence looking into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555115/knockout-js-make-every-nested-object-an-observable  ... Ill keep the question live until I crack it or someone posts a definitive answer. Cheers

Comment: I'd suggest the mapping plugin.

Comment: Instead of pasting so many code, I'd suggest you to provide a JSFiddle.