# Knockout mapping plugin - making all objects observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following Knockout viewmodel:

```
var myViewModel = {
    courseData: ko.observable(null);
};
```

I then receive the following data from the server:

```
var data = {
  "courses": [
    {
      "srcCourses": [ { "code": "001", "name": "Course 1"}, { "code": "002", "name": "Course 2"} ],
      "destCourse": { "code": "003", "name": "Course 3"}
    },
    {
      "srcCourse": [ { "code": "004", "name": "Course 4"}, { "code": "005", "name": "Course 5"} ],
      "destCourse": { "code": "006", "name": "Course 6"}
    }
  ]
}
```

I run is through the Knockout mapping plugin into my view model as follows:

```
this.courseData(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
```

This essentially leaves me with the following view model object hierarchy:

```
{
  KnockoutObservable(this.courseData): {
    KnockoutObservableArray(Courses): [
      {
        KnockoutObservableArray(srcCourses): [ ... ],
        destCourse: { KnockoutObservable(code), KnockoutObservable(name) }
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that the "destCourse" object remains an object and does not get converted to observable (although every property within the destCourse object gets converted to observable).

How can I make all child objects the data be converted to observable too? Ideally in the most generic way possible?

Comment: Please, see this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555115/knockout-js-make-every-nested-object-an-observable.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across this before and I've never been able to work out why knockout does this with child objects.

Anyway, you just need to give the mapper a bit of guidance [as described in the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

```
var coursesMapping = {
  "destCourse":{
    create:function(options){
      return ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data));
    }
  }
}

var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, coursesMapping);
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
var data = {
  "courses": [
    {
      "srcCourses": [ { "code": "001", "name": "Course 1"}, { "code": "002", "name": "Course 2"} ],
      "destCourse": { "code": "003", "name": "Course 3"}
    },
    {
      "srcCourse": [ { "code": "004", "name": "Course 4"}, { "code": "005", "name": "Course 5"} ],
      "destCourse": { "code": "006", "name": "Course 6"}
    }
  ]
}

var coursesMapping = {
  "destCourse":{
    create:function(options){
      return ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data));
    }
  }
}

var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data,coursesMapping);

console.log(mapped.courses()[0].destCourse().name()); // "Course 3"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could add your answer to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555115/knockout-js-make-every-nested-object-an-observable.  :-)

Comment: It worked beautifully - I wish all solutions were that simple. Thanks very much :)